# SQL needed for a model

Tags: sql

I have tables with data on actors, directors and movies separately but i need to find a way to input a director and output a list of all the actors that have worked with that director and all of the films those actors have been in. As this could be a very long list, they also need to limit the results in some sensible way. I have the SQL code to give out list of directors and the actors they have worked with and the movies the actor has been in with the director but we need all the movies the actors have worked in including the ones without that director?

Movie Table

```
Movie_ID         Title          Director        Release Date  
   1               A              John             2015
```

Actor Table

```
 Actor_ID       Actor_Name
```

Comment: Post your code and table definitions! Otherwise, how can we possibly help you?

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Movies Table:
Movie_ID   Title   Director   Release Date
1                    A       John         2015
2                    B       Marie        2014
3                    D       Paul          2015
etc...

Actors Table:
Actor_ID         Actor_Name
1
2

Comment: Movies Table:
Movie_ID   Title   Director   Release Date
1                    A       John         2015
2                    B       Marie        2014
3                    D       Paul          2015
etc...

Actors Table:
Actor_ID         Actor_Name
1                       Julia
2                       Will
3                       Johnny
etc....

Acts Table: (Joining Actors to Movies)
Actor ID     Movie_ID
1                    2
2                    3
3                    1
2                    1
etc.

Now how do I output a list of all of the movies of actors who have worked with a director

Comment: Don't post code as comments ***edit*** your question (make sure the sample data is formatted properly)

Comment: first write a SQL statement that includes a JOIN between all the tables.  Then add a WHERE clause to restrict to the desired information.

Comment: I dont know how to use the JOIN statements, can you give an example please @Randy

Comment: Go read about joins: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that's the structure that you have, I think you need a foreign key in the MovieTable  to be able to relate the actors with the movies they have worked in. or a diferent table where you have the ID of actors and movies they have worked in, in that way you should do something like this:

```
SELECT actor_name, title, director
FROM MovieTable m
inner join actorTable a
on m.movieID = a.actor_name
WHERE m.director = "yourImput" 
LIMIT (0,10) --limit that only displays 10 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm.. I'm not sure of the data structure partially posted in comments, but aren't you looking for something like this ?

```
SELECT Title FROM Movie m, Acts a, Actors ac 
WHERE m.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID 
AND a.Actor_ID = ac.Actor_ID
AND m.Director='the name you are looking for';
```